# Facebook Like - Won't keep track of Likes after browser refresh

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

I'm implementing Facebook's "Like" option in one of my websites as a voting tool. Users will be able to vote on a specific team by Liking the team's individual page. I have a number of teams and for some reason when I "Like" some of the teams, refresh my browser, my Like count refreshes as if I never "Liked" the page at all. However, on some of the other teams pages, when I "Like" and refresh, the count is accurate and keeps track.

I can't seem to find what is differentiating between the team pages that work and don't work. Code is identical but some keep the Like count and some don't. I was hoping someone may have experienced this before?

Below is the HTML5 Like option I used:

```
<div class="votePanel">

    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>(function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=262057453824946&xfbml=1";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

    <div class="fb-like" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="120" data-show-faces="false" data-font="arial"></div>

</div>
```

Below are my Open Graph tags:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="My Page Title" />
<meta property="og:type" content="movie" />
<meta property="og:url" content="<% response.write("http://" & Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_NAME") & Request.ServerVariables("URL")) %>" />
<meta property="og:image" content="PATHTOMYIMAGE" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Site Title" />
<meta property="og:admins" content="MYADMINID" />
<meta property="og:description" content="DESCRIPTIONHERE" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, I've got it working with a few resources.

First, I used [Facebook's Debugger](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) to check my open graph tags and make sure they were valid. I noticed that my Like button required an admin ID. Also, on the Debugger page you can actually demo your Like button and it will display an error message if necessary.

I received the message:

"The page failed to provide a valid list of administrators. It needs to specify the administrators using either a "fb:app_id" meta tag, or using a "fb:admins" meta tag to specify a comma-delimited list of Facebook users."

What I noticed was that I had my fb:admins tag mixed up with og:admins. I switched the letters up and all was fixed!

However, I'm still not sure why a few of my pages allowed the Like button to work prior to the fix.

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed this happen on my sites before too. There's usually a missing or incorrect open graph tag that's required. It's really strange how it works anyway on some pages but not others. I highly recommend using the debugger tool too. It points out what is wrong.