# Linter reporting missing tags for OG proto - tags there - xml namespaces there - possibly bad admin

Tags: facebook

The linter is reporting missing properties for the title, url, and type even though they're there.

[See this linted url for an example](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://shop.nationalgeographic.com/ngs/browse/productDetail.jsp?productId=2000745)

We're also getting behavior like this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7491111/facebook-like-wont-keep-track-of-likes-after-browser-refresh), where the like buttons loses it's count after a refresh, which is probably due to the bad admin field. It will be removed on the next deploy.

But I don't know why it's saying the url, title, and type are missing.

Answer (score 0):

This is an artifact of how the object debugger works. The admin field error was an exception in the parser, so it didn't get to look at your other tags. When you fix that one error it will be able to see the rest of your data.